# How to iterate scala map?

Tags: scala

I have scala map:

```
attrs: Map[String , String]
```

When I try to iterate over map like;

```
attrs.foreach { key, value =>     }
```

the above does not work. In each iteration I must know what is the key and what is the value. What is the proper way to iterate over scala map using scala syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`foreach` method receives `Tuple2[String, String]` as argument, not 2 arguments. So you can either use it like tuple:

```
attrs.foreach {keyVal => println(keyVal._1 + "=" + keyVal._2)}
```

or you can make pattern match:

```
attrs.foreach {case(key, value) => ...}
```

Comment: look at Rex's answer, better options there

Answer (score 165):

Three options:

```
attrs.foreach( kv => ... )          // kv._1 is the key, kv._2 is the value
attrs.foreach{ case (k,v) => ... }  // k is the key, v is the value
for ((k,v) <- attrs) { ... }        // k is the key, v is the value
```

The trick is that iteration gives you key-value pairs, which you can't split up into a key and value identifier name without either using `case` or `for`.

Answer (score 4):

I have added some more ways to iterate map values.

```
// Traversing a Map
  def printMapValue(map: collection.mutable.Map[String, String]): Unit = {

    // foreach and tuples
    map.foreach( mapValue => println(mapValue._1 +" : "+ mapValue._2))

    // foreach and case
    map.foreach{ case (key, value) => println(s"$key : $value") }

    // for loop
    for ((key,value) <- map) println(s"$key : $value")

    // using keys
    map.keys.foreach( key => println(key + " : "+map.get(key)))

    // using values
    map.values.foreach( value => println(value))
  }
```