# Confusing type mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have:

```
val words = List("all", "the", "words", "all", "the", "counts", "all", "day")
val map = Exercise02.count(words.iterator)
val expected = Map("all" -> 3, "the" -> 2, "words" -> 1, "counts" -> 1, "day" -> 1)
```

where `Exercise02.count` is `java.util.Iterator[String] => Map[String, Int]` and merely produces a count of each word in the input `java.util.Iterator[String]`.

I wrote a test:

```
object Exercise02Spec extends FlatSpec with Inspectors {
  val words = List("all", "the", "words", "all", "the", "counts", "all", "day")
  val map = Exercise02.count(words.iterator)
  val expected = Map("all" -> 3, "the" -> 2, "words" -> 1, "counts" -> 1, "day" -> 1)

  "count" should "count the occurrence of each word" in {
    forAll (map) { kv => assert(kv._2 === expected(kv._1)) }
    // forAll (map) { (k: String, v: Int) => assert(v === expected(k)) }
  }
}
```

The first line compiles just fine, and the test passes. If I replace the first line with the commented out second line, I get a compilation error.

- sbt reports: `found : (String, Int) => Unit, required: ((String, Int)) => Unit`
- IntelliJ IDEA reports: `Type mismatch, expected: ((String, Int)) => Unit, actual: (String, Int) => Unit`

Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate scala map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364468/how-to-iterate-scala-map)

Comment: Seems like you're missing `case` when matching the map value into the tuple. Try `forAll (map) { case (k: String, v: Int) => assert(v === expected(k)) }`. Any reason why you're not just checking whether `assert(map == expected)` for map equality?

Comment: Because once I went down this path, I wanted to understand why `(k: String, v: Int) => assert(v === expected(k))` is not acceptable. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using accepts a function that transforms a *single* argument to a single output. What you're telling Scala in your second statement is that map should accept a function with two arguments! There's an important difference between a *single* argument that just happens to be a tuple of size two, and two distinct arguments.

So you have single argument, but you (and Scala) know it's a tuple. To access those two elements, you have to *destructure* or *pattern match* your argument against the tuple you want. You just do that by writing `forAll (map) { case (k: String, v: Int) => assert(v === expected(k)) }`. You're saying the argument you receive should match the pattern of a tuple `(String, Int)` and you want the first element bound to `k` and the second to `v`. You could probably eliminate mentioning the types explicitly here. Note that this is similar to the syntax used in pattern matching, which is essentially what you're doing here.

Comment: What exactly is `case (k: String, v: Int)` such that it *does* satisfy the expected requires for `forAll (map)` ?

Comment: It means "the single argument I'm getting here should look like (k: String, v: Int)". So you're only accepting a single argument, which is what the function needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd example you're defining a two argument function, not a single tuple argument function. Hence why the error is saying it is expecting the double parenthesis around the argument.

Comment: Yes, but why does wrapping it in a second set of parentheses not fix it?

Comment: I assumed it would. An interesting question :) Could do the partial function way then, with { case (k,v) => ... }

Comment: @user3706801 I would definitely go with the pattern match statement. Just answered with that until I saw this comment.